# SQL - How to find all linked ids from a table

Tags: sql, oracle

I have a table that shows the relationships between people a bit like this.

```
id  linked_id
1   2
1   3
3   4
4   1
```

There is no apparent order to the table or the relationships.

I'm trying to find a way to list all the ids that have any kind of link to a given id. So for examples from the table above:

id = 1 would return 1, 2, 3 and 4.
id = 2 would also return 1, 2, 3 and 4

It's an oracle database, and the query would have to be in plain SQL. Thanks for your help, this has been driving me nuts.

Comment: Basically just tried union of two queries returning results from either column. After I realised that there were some indirect relationships in the table, and that I couldn't tell how deep those links could possibly go, I've been stuck. Mostly been asking friends, and googling with no clue what to search for.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use something like this:

```
SELECT linked_id
  FROM DATA
 START WITH ID = :1
CONNECT BY NOCYCLE PRIOR ID = linked_id
        OR ID = PRIOR linked_id
UNION
SELECT ID
  FROM DATA
 START WITH linked_id = :1
CONNECT BY NOCYCLE PRIOR ID = linked_id
        OR ID = PRIOR linked_id
UNION
SELECT :1 FROM dual
```

Comment: Excellent. Thanks for the quick response, I've never used a start with .. connect by clause. For some reason, the OR condition actually removed some valid results, but taking that out seems to have fixed the problem. I'll have look a bit more but definitely seems the correct answer.